# É possivel executar uma página externa no cliente e obter o resultado JSON utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json

boa tarde!

É o seguinte, tenho uma URL de um forum na Internet que ao acessá-la ela retorna no formato JSON os últimos posts visualizados por um determinado usuário. Como ela é externa não sei como funciona e acredito que seja pelos cookies que o forum deixou no computador do usuário.

Eu queria usar essa URL para quando o usuário entrar no meu site eu colocar algo do tipo: "5 Últimos posts visualizados por você no FORUM TAL".

Mas só que pra fazer isso essa URL teria que ser executada de alguma forma no navegador do cliente e eu ainda teria que ter acesso ao conteúdo retornado por essa URL.

Existe a possibilidade de eu fazer isso usando o PHP ou alguma outra tecnologia?

Obrigado!

Comment: Essa url é pública? Ou é disponibilizada apenas para para você, desenvolvedor? Esse forum não disponibiliza API?

Comment: Através de um `iframe` provavelmente você vai conseguir colocar os últimos posts visualizados.

Comment: A API é privada deles, sem contar que os posts aparecem quando a URL é executada pq só eles podem ler os cookies. No caso do iframe alguém tem algum exemplo?

Comment: vou fazer uns teste e respondo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode usar Ajax para isso. Ex:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'URL DE RETORNO JSON',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $('body').append(data.titulo);
  }
})
```

no caso é so modificar conforme o retorno do JSON

Comment: Testei aqui deu certo amigo! Valeu!